# Will range-for in c++ calls item's copy constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, for-loop

`PanelItem` is a class that does not have copy constructor(`=Deleted`). I use `QList<PanelItem> m_arrPanelItems` to store them.

When I call `QList::append(const T &value)`, an error `'PanelItem::PanelItem(const PanelItem &)': attempting to reference a deleted function` occur. I think it calls `PanelItem::PanelItem(const PanelItem &)` inside the function.

When I use *range-for*, the error appeared **again**. I use the `const auto&` in *range_declaration*. So I think the copy constructor `PanelItem::PanelItem(const PanelItem &)` will not be used.

```cpp
// QList<PanelItem> m_arrPanelItems
for (const auto& t_item : this->m_arrpPanelItems) {
    // do something 
}
```

Why?

Comment: It seems like you said you can't add them to the container in the first place, so what's in the container you're trying to iterate over?

Comment: @RetiredNinja perhaps the items are emplaced/moved into the list instead of copied? Who knows. But the range-based for loop should not be invoking copy semantics when using a reference variable. If it is, something is broken

Comment: [*The values stored in the various containers can be of any assignable data type. To qualify, a type must provide a copy constructor, and an assignment operator.*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#assignable-data-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QList::append(const T &value)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#append) "Inserts value at the end of the list." - From both the signature and its functionality it should be obvious that `T` needs to have a copy constructor for this function to work...

As **thuga** so already pointed out, types to be stored in e.g. `QList` **must** be [assignable types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#assignable-data-type) - which means they need to have a copy constructor - in order to be a valid type to be put inside a `QList`. For Types without copy-constructor (and/or assignment operator) the API even states you need to store **pointers** (`T*`) instead.

Even if you somehow manage to put types *without* a copy constructor into the `QList` you violate that requirement, causing all kind of undefined behaviour: The error in the range declaration might e.g. stem from some kind of internal magic `QList` is doing (it is e.g. an [implicitly shared](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) type), but this is all moot, since you are not permitted to put a type without copy constructors into `QList`s in the first place. In other words: Garbage in, Garbage out.